# Подскажите как на PHP коде можно вычислить количество сообщений отправленных определенным пользователем в одной статье за 5 минут?

Tags: php

Имеется база в таком формате:
[image: База данных]

Сверстал вот такую форму:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как на PHP коде можно вычислить количество сообщений отправленных определенным пользователем в одной статье за 5 минут?

Comment: сделать счетчик в cookie, но это можно просто обойти. надежнее всего считать при помощи sql запроса к бд.

Comment: Хочу этот способ попробовать именно в веб-части (не просто так php написал) для определения флудящих юзеров. В запросах не силен, поэтому и задал вопрос. Если знаете как это определить по SQL, напишите

Comment: Условие для последних пяти минут `UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - date < 300`

Comment: Спасибо за условие

Answer (score 0):

Запрос в базу на количество добавленных сообщений юзером в эту статью за период 5 минут и в результате получите цифру количества.

Comment: Я понял, но как этот запрос должен выглядеть?

Comment: можно вместо unix_timestamp CURRENT_TIMESTAMP использовать

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам:

```
if (query("SELECT count(*) FROM `comments` WHERE pid = ? AND uid = ? AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - date < 300",array($_GET['id'], 0))->fetchColumn() >= 5) exit(json_encode([$lang['FLOOD'],false]));
else if (strlen($_POST['comment']) > 128) exit(json_encode([$lang['COMMENT_LONG_LENGTH'],false]));
else {
query("INSERT INTO `comments`(`pid`, `uid`, `date`, `text`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)",array($_GET['id'],0,time(),htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment'])));
exit(json_encode([$lang['COMMENT_SUCCESS'],true]));
}
```